# Python error when reading from csv file and accepting input from user

Tags: python, csv

my code (shown below) keep returning the programmed in errors, for example, if I enter 0, it stills states the answer is invalid, I know there is something I'm overlooking, any help would be appreciated!
(sorry if it's really simple and I just hadn't noticed, it's my first time coding)

```
 with open ("Lineup.csv", "rt") as fileopen:
    file = csv.reader(fileopen, delimiter=',')
    array = []
    score = 0


    for row in file:
        array.append(row)

    for i in array:
        like = ""
        likeness = ""
        print(i)
        like = print(input("If 1 is yes and 0 is no, do you like/know this band?"))
        if like == "0":
            score + 0
            like = ""
        if like == 1:
            print(i)
            like = 0
            likeness = print(int(input("If 1 is worst and 3 is best, how much do you like them?")))
            if likeness == 1:
                score + 1
                likeness = 0
            if likeness == 2:
                score + 2
                likeness = 0
            if likeness == 3:
                score + 3
                likeness = 0
            else:
                print(i)
                likeness = print(int(input("Answer was not valid, please choose a number from 1-3, how much do you like this band?")))
        else:
            print(i)
            like = print(input("Answer was not valid, please choose 0 or 1, do you like this band?"))

    file.close
```

Comment: `like` never gets a value, because you're assigning a `print` to it (and the same case farther down). Remove your `print`, `input` prints the question anyways. Also note you check for equality against the string `"0"` and the integer `1`. Make the second a string as well.

Comment: Also, use `elif` instead of just a whole bunch of `if` statements. Additionally, you don't need to set `like` and `likeness` to be empty strings before assigning them. And you better use a `while` loop if you want to continue asking until you get valid input.

Comment: Can you provide an example of your csv file?

Comment: The elif thing really helped and it works now so thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open ("Lineup.csv", "rt") as fileopen:
    file = csv.reader(fileopen, delimiter=',')
    array = []
    score = 0


    for row in file:
        array.append(row)

    for i in array:
        like = ""
        likeness = ""
        print(i)
        like =input("If 1 is yes and 0 is no, do you like/know this band?")
        print like
        if like == "0":
            score + 0
            like = ""
        if like == 1:
            print(i)
            like = 0
            likeness = int(input("If 1 is worst and 3 is best, how much do you like them?"))
            print likeness
            if likeness == 1:
                score + 1
                likeness = 0
            if likeness == 2:
                score + 2
                likeness = 0
            if likeness == 3:
                score + 3
                likeness = 0
            else:
                print(i)
                likeness = print(int(input("Answer was not valid, please choose a number from 1-3, how much do you like this band?")))
        else:
            print(i)
```

When you print a value,  it is not assigned to the variable.  Just fix that and it works.

Comment: Try with 1, see if it works. Also there is the same issue farther down with `print`.

Comment: I missed that.  The code seems "homework"y so i wasn't going to heavily modify the logic in it.  A proper solution would require an input loop.

Comment: I'm open to any modifications you guys think, I'm trying to learn code myself so I'm setting myself tasks to do, so really, edit as much as you need as long as it works!